# Resizing and correctly positioning parallax image

Tags: html, css, parallax

most historical threads covering this weren't what I specifically needed, or their screenshots/linked files were no longer accessible via the internet, making it too hard to follow.

I would like my parallax image to cover the left half of the page, from top to bottom. It's a profile shot of myself sitting. I think stretching height/width to 100% and 50% respectively should do the trick but I am unsure of how to implement it. As of now the gray portion sits horizontally in the center, I'd like it on the right hand portion of the page.

I am also trying to put my navigation bar on the top of the right hand side of the screen, fixed in a header position as well.

- `background-position: left;` does not always move the image to the left (from the center). I assume this is because I'm not using height/width in percentiles but rather pixel height etc.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="index.html" class=active>
    
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <meta name="description" content="Learn about me, tutoring services, resume and more.">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    
  <title>Me | Home</title>
    
    <!--    GOOGLE FONTS
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1671.6">
    
    <style>
        .parallax {
            /* Image to be used */
            background-image: url("me_main_2.png");
            min-height: 500px;

            /*scrolling effect*/
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: left;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: auto;
        }
    
    
    /* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones. Increase the pixels if needed 
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1366px) {
    .parallax {
    background-attachment: scroll;
     }
     }
    */
        
    </style>
    
    
</head>
<body>

    <div class="parallax"></div>
    <div style="height:400px;background-color:lightgray;font-size:28px">

    <center>
        <nav>
          <ul id="mainMenu">
            <li><a href="about me.html">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="Tutoring Services.html">Tutoring Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="Resume.html">Resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="photography_portfolio/photography%20portfolio.html">Photography Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>  
            <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
     </center>
        
        <br><br><br>
        
        <p><center>
        This is a personal and professional website, designed solely by myself (as a personal project) with the aim of displaying my resume, contact information and other items in an accessible manner for interested parties to see.     
        </center></p>
        
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* Nav Bar */

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

/* Centered text */
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Thanks as always for taking the time.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want can you pls add the picture of an expected output

Comment: My apologies - I had trouble framing the question. 

This template is probably the closest to what I want (sans the nav bar which I want rooted on the top left half). 

http://www.templatefoundation.com/previews/miller/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The following is what you want but the problem is that when the screen shrink the link will wrap to the next line but other ways it worked

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}

.parallax {
  z-index: 9999;
  /* Image to be used */
  background: url('x.png') no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*scrolling effect*/
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: left;
  background-size: auto;
}

@charset "UTF-8";

/* Nav Bar */

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}


/* Centered text */

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones. Increase the pixels if needed 
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1366px) {
    .parallax {
    background-attachment: scroll;
     }
     }
    */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="index.html" class=active>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <meta name="description" content="Learn about me, tutoring services, resume and more.">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <title>Me | Home</title>
  <!--    GOOGLE FONTS
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        -->

  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1671.6">


</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="parallax"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center;height:400px;background-color:lightgray;font-size:28px">

    <nav>
      <ul id="mainMenu">
        <li><a href="about me.html">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="Tutoring Services.html">Tutoring Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="Resume.html">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="photography_portfolio/photography%20portfolio.html">Photography Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <br><br><br>

    <p>
      This is a personal and professional website, designed solely by myself (as a personal project) with the aim of displaying my resume, contact information and other items in an accessible manner for interested parties to see.
    </p>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have gotten this far with my original code by changing the alignment to left, however the image crops and is not centered, and will not fill the position. See the link for my problem:

https://imgur.com/thpQ6Vv

.
Edit: The image size I want to use is 3.6mb, 1341 × 2063, if that helps. So it's rather large.